# Django - display all products created by a user

Tags: python, django, permissions, view

I have built a product app where a logged in user can create products by filling out a form.  There is a products page that lists all products created by all users.  When a user clicks on the profile link they will see a list of products they have created.  When a user is logged in their username appears in the nav bar (this will be relevant further down this post).

I want to create a page where visitors can can view products by user.  I created this view:

```
def designs_by(request, username):
    user = get_object_or_404(User.objects, username=username)
    products = Product.objects.filter(user=user)
    return render(request, 'designs_by.html', {'user':user,'products': products})
```

with this url:

```
url(r'^designs_by/(\w+)/$', views.designs_by, name='designs_by'),
```

which works, for the most part, but when a visitor clicks on the link to view the products by a user, the users profile link appears in the nav bar.  The link won't work but I have no clue why it appears. Yeah, an odd one.

EDIT:  Here's the code for the right navbar where the login / profile / logout functions are displayed:

```
<ul class="navbar-nav navbar-right">
    {% if user.is_authenticated %}
            <li><a class="navbar-text navbar-right" href="{% url 'profile' user.username %}">
    {% if user.first_name and user.last_name %} {{user.first_name}} {{user.last_name}} {% else %} {{ user.username }} {% endif %} </a></li>
            <li><a class="navbar-text navbar-right" href="{% url 'Logout' %}">&nbsp;Logout </a></li>
    {% else %}
            <li><a class="navbar-text navbar-right" href="{% url 'Login' %}">Login </a></li>
    {% endif %}
</ul>
```

Here's the screenshot of the navbar - note I have not logged into the app, yet the profile name shows.

[image]

EDIT 2: here's the profile view:

```
def profile(request, username):
    user = get_object_or_404(User.objects, username=username)
    products = Product.objects.filter(user=user)
    if not request.user == user:
        return render(request, 'no.html')
    else:
        return render(request, 'profile.html', {'user':user,'products': products})
```

Answer (score 0):

1. change `get_object_or_404(User.objects` to `get_object_or_404(User`
2. change `url(r'^designs_by/(\w+)/$'` to `url(r'^designs_by/(?P<username>\w+)/$'`

for the template;

```
<ul class="navbar-nav navbar-right">
  {% if request.user.is_authenticated %}
    <li>
      <a class="navbar-text navbar-right" href="{% url 'profile' username=request.user.username %}">
        {% if request.user.first_name and request.user.last_name %}
          {{ request.user.first_name }} {{ request.user.last_name }}
        {% else %}
          {{ request.user.username }}
        {% endif %}
      </a>
    </li>
    <li><a class="navbar-text navbar-right" href="{% url 'Logout' %}">&nbsp;Logout </a></li>
  {% else %}
    <li><a class="navbar-text navbar-right" href="{% url 'Login' %}">Login </a></li>
  {% endif %}
</ul>
```

Comment: I edited per your reply (assuming the details after the comma in the get_object statement are the same).  Same issue, the user profile link appears in the nav bar along with the logout link.  I'm using <a href="/designs_by/{{product.user.username}}/"> to call the username since user.username and username don't work.

Comment: please read the docs how to use url in the template. it should be `href="{% url 'designs_by' username=product.user.username %}"`

Comment: Thanks - but - same issue.

Comment: The link for the user profile appears in the nav bar, even though the user is not logged in.

Comment: We can't tell how the nav bar works because we don't have the code for it.

Comment: I've added the navbar code and screenshot to the main question.

Comment: you need to change `user.username` to `request.user.username`

Comment: That threw this error: Reverse for 'profile' with arguments '('',)' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['user/(\\w+)/$']

Comment: def profile(request, username):
    user = get_object_or_404(User.objects, username=username)
    products = Product.objects.filter(user=user)
    if not request.user == user:
        return render(request, 'no.html')
    else:
        return render(request, 'profile.html', {'user':user,'products': products})

Comment: change `get_object_or_404(User.objects, username=username)` to `get_object_or_404(User, username=username)`

Answer (score 0):

**I take it back - this did not work - I'm back to having the issue.**

I changed the navbar right code to this and it worked. It was the anonymous portion that was tripping up the process.

```
<ul class="navbar-nav navbar-right">
    {% if user.is_authenticated and user.is_anonymous %}
        <li><a class="navbar-text navbar-right" href="{% url 'profile' user.username %}">
            {% if user.first_name and user.last_name %} {{user.first_name}} {{user.last_name}} {% else %} {{ user.username }} {% endif %} </a></li>
        <li><a class="navbar-text navbar-right" href="{% url 'Logout' %}">&nbsp;Logout </a></li>
            {% else %}
        <li><a class="navbar-text navbar-right" href="{% url 'Login' %}">Login </a></li>
            {% endif %}
        </ul>
```